# Z-index on different positioned elements in the same page

Tags: css, position, tailwind-css, css-position, z-index

**The problem:**
Buttons that suppose to be behind are in front.
[image]
**Description:**
I have a react app using Tailwind css.

There are two different components on the same page that in both I am using `position: relative` on a container div, and `position: absolute` on the child div:

1. a calendar that opens `onClick` and positioned according to its container.
2. a button that has a span when `onHover` its shows and specifies the action of the button. (used twice as seen in the image)

This is the **calendar** jsx:

```
<div className='relative flex items-center gap-2 xs:flex-col z-[9999]'>
      <label
        className='w-max px-2 flex gap-1 py-1 cursor-pointer md:w-full rounded-md bg-white'
        onClick={() => setIsCalendar((prev) => !prev)}
      >
        {format(selectedDay, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}
        <ArrowDownCircleIcon className='w-5' />
      </label>

      {isCalendar && (
        <div
          ref={calendarRef}
          className={`absolute top-10 shadow-lg bg-light w-max py-2 rounded-xl z-[9999]`}
        >
          {visualCalendar}
          <div className='w-11/12 flex justify-end'>
            <Button type='button' theme='full' text='OK' className='text-xs' onClick={() => setIsCalendar(false)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
```

This is the **button** jsx:

```
<button
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`group relative`}
      type={type}
    >
      {children}
      <span onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      className={`absolute opacity-0 w-max group-hover:opacity-100 bg-sky-400 text-light text-xs p-1 cursor-default
      rounded-lg transition-opacity duration-400 -z-1
      -bottom-6 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2
      `}>
            {hoverText}
        </span>
    </button>
```

**What I've tried:**

setting a `z-index: 9999` to each of the calendar elements.

I also checked and there aren't any `position` nor `z-index` to parent / child elements for these two components.

WHAT AM I MISSING?

Comment: Seems like you'd need to rationalize the [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) on the page, so that you can stack the stacking context that contains the calendar over the stacking context that contains the button where the two stacking contexts are within the same stacking context. You have obfuscated too much of the page code for us to be able to identify this for you unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your the response I fixed it. Thank you. Ive added a z-index to the container of the element that holds the calendar component and is a sibling to the main element that contains the buttons. But what I dont understand is why the calendar is clearly on top of the main element that contains the buttons, even before i set its z-index. doesnt make sense at all.